# chartjs-plugin-streaming: onRefresh() callback isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, electron, chart.js, real-time

Hello  I'm new in javascript world; I'm trying to display random numbers in real time with **Chart.js** and **chartjs-plugin-streaming** starting from a tutorial code which I started to modify for my scope.

```
const Chart= require ("chart.js");
const chartStreaming = require('chartjs-plugin-streaming');
const boxWhiteColor = "#2043CE";
const pressure_graph = document.getElementById('pressureGraph').getContext('2d');
Chart.register(chartStreaming);
let pressure_graph_config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Pressure',
            data: [],
            borderColor: boxWhiteColor,
            fill: false
          }]
        }, 
    
        options: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'PRESSURE',
            fontColor: boxWhiteColor, 
            fontSize: 30
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                display: true, 
                drawBorder: true, 
                color: boxWhiteColor, 
                lineWidth: 5},
              ticks: {
                fontColor: boxWhiteColor,
                display: false
              },
              
              type: 'realtime',
               realtime: {
                duration: 10000,
                refresh: 100, // plot at 10 Hz
                delay:200,
                pause: false,     // chart is not paused
                ttl: undefined,   // data will be automatically deleted as it disappears off the chart
                frameRate: 100,    // data points are drawn 100 times every second
                onRefresh: chart => {  
                  
                  console.log(trocarP.data.datasets.data);
                  chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                    chart.data.dataset[0].data.push({
                      x: Date.now(),
                      y: Math.random() //pressure16bits[pressure16bits.length-1]
                    });
                  });
                 
                }
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: '[mmHg]', fontColor: boxWhiteColor, fontSize: 30, fontStyle: 900,
              },
              ticks: {
                fontColor: boxWhiteColor,
                fontSize: 25,
                fontStyle: 700,
                maxTicksLimit: 5,
                min: 0,
                max: 40,
              },
              gridLines: {display: true, drawBorder: true, color: boxWhiteColor, lineWidth: 5},
            }]
          },
          elements: { 
            point: {radius: 0},
          },
          legend: { display: false}
        }
    }
    trocarP = new Chart (pressure_graph, pressure_graph_config);
```

The problem is the graph is being created on a canvas via the `.html` file, but then it doesn't display anything; trying to debug the code I found out that the `console.log()` I placed inside the `onRefresh` callback is not printing anything, so **I'm assuming the callback isn't working**. Any clue on what's happening?

[Screenshot of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QNvC.png)

**Edit**: I noticed that also Y axis label has not been displayed. I don't get what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/2ogLwth0/9/

Comment: That's strange, I'm using electron js and having troubles, do you have any hint of possible issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using v2 syntax while using v3 of the lib this wont work as there are several breaking changes, see [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html) for all of them.

For example, way of defining scales has changed, you need an adapter for dates and more.

working basic v3 example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'realtime',
        realtime: {
          duration: 20000,
          refresh: 100,
          delay: 200,
          onRefresh: chart => {
            const now = Date.now();
            chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
              dataset.data.push({
                x: now,
                y: Math.random()
              });
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-streaming/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-streaming.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm starting to understand what my problem is linked to! Now for example if I want to use luxon as date adapter and since I'm working on Electron js, do you know which file should I include in the `.html` file in order to take the date adapter into account? @LeeLenalee

Comment: Guess you just need to insta and import it the same way as you do with chart.js itself and the streaming plugin

Comment: I'm linking the `luxon.js` file found on the luxon documentation page at my `.html` file, but now I got an error from `chart.js` at line 7348. I "solved" the problem commenting that line, now The graph is working thanks!